# Override Resource Only on Single Module

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a design system library for my whole app. In the design system library `colors.xml` I have this color

```
<color name="color_button_primary">@color/red</color>
```

What I trying to achieve is I want to override this color only on one of the module in my app. So I created `colors.xml` in X module

```
<color name="color_button_primary">@color/green</color>
```

The problem is all of primary button in my app turn green. Is there a way I can achieve this only on a single module?